# Javax: Extending named service

Tags: java, spring

In my application I have several beans which use services. The services are annotated with `@Named("Name")` and injected with `@Inject`.

I have a service. I have an interface and and implementation for it.
In another module of my application I can use this service in many ways, but some methods need to be different and I need new ones. So I wanted to extend the first service with another one.

I came up with something like this:

```
Interface Service1 {...}

@Named(Service1)
Class Service1Impl implements Service1 {...}

Interface SpecialService1 extends Service1 {...}

@Named(SpecialService1)
Class SpecialService1 extends Service1Impl implements SpecialService1 {...}
```

Of course, when I start my server, I get the message that there is no qualifying bean with the type `Service1`, because there are two matches of classes implementing Service1.

But I need to extend `Service1` in `SpecialService1` to access all methods and I need to extend `Service1Impl` in `SpecialService1Impl` so that I don't have to implement everything again.

In my bean I just want to inject `SpecialService1` and access all methods of `Service1` and `SpecialService1`.

Do you have any idea how I could get such a construct to work?

Comment: If your bean is both `Service1` and `SpecialService1` you only need to register the `SpecialService1` and not the other one.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. In other beans I only need to inject Service1. In another Bean I need SpecialService1. I inject only one of them per bean. But I have to put @Named above both services to be able to inject one of them.

Comment: No you don't... Your `SpecialService1` is also a `Service1`... So you only need an instance of `SpecialService1` to fullfil the role of both... If you really need 2 instances you will need to differ between them, by using a `@Qualifier`... You might want to mark your `@Service1` as `@Primary` so that is used by default and the other one is selectivly injected.

Comment: Yes I need to be able to use them differently. In some areas of my application I need Service1, because I want to use the original methods and in one area I need the overwritten versions, so I need SpecialService1. But the @Primary annotation works fine. That way I only have to flag the specialService. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague gave me a tip and I got it to work.

Everywhere where I want to inject one of the services I have to add `@Qualifier("Service1")`. That way he knows which service to inject.

Do you have a more elegant solution for this? Else I would accept this as the answer for the question.

Edit: As stated in a comment above, I also used `@Primary` for the Service1. That way I only have to flag the Inject with SpecialService1 with `@Qualifier`